# Guzzle Gmail API messages request fails - Login Required

Tags: php, gmail-api, guzzle

I try to get a list of messages from the currently logged in user.  I am using Guzzle client to make a request. Unfortunately I don't quite understand the Google docs about the API.

This is what I have so far:

```
$client = new Client;

$headers = [
    'content-type' => 'application/json',
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$token->access_token
];

$params = [
    'maxResults'    => 10,
    'client_id'     => config('gmail.clientId'),
    'client_secret' => config('gmail.clientSecret'),
];

$response = $client->get('https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages', [
    $headers,
    $params
]);
```

With this code I receive a message "Error 401 - Login Required". How can I achieve this? In my application every user is connected to their own Gmail account. The `access_token`s are saved in a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the Google API that you are using, but you definitely have a Guzzle-related mistake:

```
$response = $client->get('https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages', [
    'headers' => $headers,
    'query' => $params,
]);
```

Also according to [the docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list), you don't need to supply `client_id` and `client_secret` upon every request. Take a look at [Google's official auth lib for PHP](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-php), or/and at [the complete SDK](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client).

Comment: Thank you so much! With showing me my guzzle-related mistake I was able to receive my messages! Thanks :)